# Creating objects in loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

I am creating a simplistic poker game in Java that will create a deck of cards, let you draw a hand and display what kind of suit you have. Here is what I have so far and have run into a problem.

I have 3 different Array Lists, one for the card values, one for the card suits, and one to hold the actual card objects once the card suit and value is applied. I created a loop that is supposed to add a suit to each value (13 values) and add them into the newCards ArrayList (it is of type CARD, a different class I have that allows the objects to have both an integer and a string). After I try to print out newCards to see if it works properly. I get quite a few exception errors.

I'm not sure how to efficiently create a loop like this so any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
public class pokerMain {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        ArrayList<String> suits = new ArrayList<String>();//array list for the card suits
        ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>();//array list for card values
        ArrayList<CARDS> newCards = new ArrayList<CARDS>();//array list for cards with assigned val/suits

        suits.add("Clubs");//These are the suits, added to the suits ArrayList
        suits.add("Hearts");
        suits.add("Diamonds");
        suits.add("Spades");

        System.out.println("suits contains: " + suits );//Testing for suit

        for(int i = 1; i <= 13; i ++){//loop that adds all 13 values to to the val ArrayList
            val.add(i);
        }

        System.out.println("val contains " + val);//Testing for val
```

This is the loop

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= val.size(); i ++){//This loop will be used to add a suit to every card value

        newCards.add(new CARDS(suits.get(0), val.get(i)));//assigns hearts
        newCards.add(new CARDS(suits.get(1), val.get(i)));//assigns hearts
        newCards.add(new CARDS(suits.get(2), val.get(i)));//assigns diamonds
        newCards.add(new CARDS(suits.get(3), val.get(i)));//assigns spades
    }
-------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    System.out.println(newCards.toString());//prints newCards arrayList

    //newCards.add(card);// puts card object into array list newCards
```

Comment: Could you add the exception trace you mentioned please?

Comment: To comply with most common Java coding guideliines, CARDS should be named Card.

Comment: You're getting an index out of bounds exception because you are going from 0 to size(). That makes it a total of size()+1 elements. The last element is size()-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent code duplication you could try two loops and use for each

```
for(String s : suits) {
    for(Integer i : val) {
        newCards.add(new CARDS(s, i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as John Mercier said, for:each is the way to go here.

Secondly, and this isn't causing your problem, but CARDS is not exactly a conventional class name.  Something like Card or Cards (or wrap the Card in a Deck class...).

Thirdly, and most importantly, the main() doesn't seem to be your problem, as far as I can tell.  Check your CARDS class.

Comment: ArrayList.toString will work since AbstractCollection overrides it. You may be thinking about arrays, in which case Arrays.toString will do the trick.

Comment: My bad.  I thought it just inherited from Object.